# Is it possible to get a list of all the current collision objects using the MoveIt API?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like to get a list of all the collision object currently in the planning scene using the C++ MoveIt API.

My main goal is to be able to clear all collision objects in the environment. My approach will be to obtain a list of all the current collision objects which I can then iteratively delete using the object list.

System: Ubuntu 16.04 & ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343970/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-current-collision-objects-using-the-moveit-api?/) by [sdfryc](https://answers.ros.org/users/40154/sdfryc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use planning scene interface class to manipulate collision objects. You can directly remove all existing collision objects with `removeCOllisionObejects`() or get a list of current objects with `getCollisionObejcts`()

Refer to the related API interface
[here](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1PlanningSceneInterface.html)

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2020-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdfryc](https://answers.ros.org/users/40154/sdfryc/) on 2020-02-13**:
Thanks, atas.

I'm now able to get a list of the collision objects in the scene using getCollisionObjects(). However, for some reason I'm unable to remove collision objects using removeCollisionObjects().

For example I tried:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "remove_collision");
    ros::NodeHandle node_handle("~");

    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
    spinner.start();

    moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface current_scene;
    sleep(1.0);

    std::vector<std::string> object_ids;
    object_ids.push_back("box1");
    current_scene.removeCollisionObjects(object_ids);
    ROS_INFO("remove an object from the world");

    ros::shutdown();
}
```

Perhaps that is a question for a new thread. For now I'm able to remove the objects using the planning scene diffs via a rosservice call to '/apply_planning_scene'.

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-10-11**:\

> get a list of current objects with `getCollisionObjects()`

That's unavailable